# Aggregating a large amount of data based on limits

Tags: sql-server, database, aggregation

Table LargeData contains large ammount of data (1 million rows)
that can be changed in any moment

Structure:

```
Id, StringA, StringB, .... , StringN, NumericA, NumericB, ... , NumericK
```

and data:

```
1, "Some", "Different", ... , "Key", 100, 500, ... 300

2, "Some", "Different", ... , "Key", 110, 510, ... 310

3, "More", "Different", ... , "Key", 120, 520, ... 320
....
```

Table Limits contains list of limits (10 thousand rows) (3 String values and 1 Numeric Value as limit)
with structure:

```
(Id, StringKey1, StringValue1, StringKey2, StringValue2, StringKey3, StringValue3, NumericKey, NumericValue)
```

and data:

```
11, "StringA", "Some", "StringB", "Different", "StringC", "Key", "NumericA", 500

12, "StringA", "More", "StringB", "Different", "StringC", "Key", "NumericB", 600

....
```

How would you build solution that will show Records from Limits table containing Aggregated Sum of NumericKey column with matching StringKey/Values combination

At example for that data it would be:

```
Id, Limit, CurrentSum

11, 500,   210

12, 600,   520
....
```

Need some solution/approach for aggregating data from variable numeric column from table based on variable both matching column, got any ideas?

Comment: Large amount of data that can be changed how? Does that mean the table will change or the data within? Where did `limit` and `current sum` come from?

Comment: String & Numeric values can change, rows can be added or deleted, Limit is NumericValue from Limits, CurrentSum is Sum(NumericA) for 1 row, Sum(NumericB) for 2 row, both summed only for corresponding String/Keys combination